# uploading file and saving path, name, type in oracle database in the system

Tags: jsp, struts2, oracle10g

I have to upload a file and save the file name, path where the file is saved in the system and file type(.pdf, .txt etc) into oracle database. I have done the file upload path and also written code for saving in the database but values are not getting saved in the database. I'm new to struts2 so please anyone can help..

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<s:head />
</head>

<s:actionerror />

<s:form action="uploadAction" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <s:file name="uploadFile" label="Choose File" size="40" />
   <s:submit value="Upload" name="submit" />
</s:form>
```

success.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
 <body>
   File uploaded successfully...!!!

   File Name : <s:property value="uploadFileFileName"/> <br>
   Content Type : <s:property value="uploadFileContentType"/> <br>
   Temp File Name : <s:property value="uploadFile"/>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Action class:

```
package java4s;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LogingEx extends ActionSupport{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private File uploadFile;
    private String uploadFileContentType;
    private String uploadFileFileName;


    public File getUploadFile() {
        return uploadFile;
    }
    public void setUploadFile(File uploadFile) {
        this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
    }

    public String getUploadFileContentType() {
        return uploadFileContentType;
    }
    public void setUploadFileContentType(String uploadFileContentType) {
        this.uploadFileContentType = uploadFileContentType;
    }

    public String getUploadFileFileName() {
        return uploadFileFileName;
    }
    public void setUploadFileFileName(String uploadFileFileName) {
        this.uploadFileFileName = uploadFileFileName;
    }

    public String execute()
    {

        try{
        String filePath = "c:/Myuploads";  // Path where uploaded file will be stored
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath); // check your path in console
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, uploadFileFileName);// Create file name  same as original
        FileUtils.copyFile(uploadFile, fileToCreate); // Just copy temp file content tos this file      
        System.out.println("inside database");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.1.62:1521:mcrtest","SULTAN","SULTAN");
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("insert into filedatabase " +"(name, type, path)" + "values(?,?,?)");
        statement.setString(1,uploadFileFileName);
        statement.setString(2,uploadFileContentType);
        statement.setString(3,uploadFile.toString());
        System.out.println("After database");
        statement.close();
        con.close();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;

        }


        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
    <package name="a" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="uploadAction" class="java4s.LogingEx"> 

            <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
            <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
            <interceptor-ref name="debugging" />
            <interceptor-ref name="profiling" />
            <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven" />
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">102400</param>
            <param name="allowedExtensions"> .doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.txt,.pdf,.zip </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
            <param name="excludeParams"> dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods"> input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
            <param name="excludeMethods"> input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>

            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: I'm not using hibernate.

Comment: You need to execute your `PreparedStatement`.